# Acessar item especifico dentro de uma collection no firebase utilizando angular

Tags: angular, firebase, firestore

Estou com um projeto angular e estou usando o firebase cloud firestore como banco de dados porém estou com uma dificuldade em utilizar pois tenho uma coleção chamada feed e dentro dessa coleção tenho vários itens e estou precisando pegar apenas um item utilizando a key dele porém todos o métodos que eu tentei não funcionaram.

meu serviço:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';


@Injectable()

export class TestService {
  constructor(private firestore: AngularFirestore) { }
  /* create_NewIcecream : Cria um novo registro na coleção especificada usando o método add */
  criar_novo_user(record) {
    return this.firestore.collection('user').add(record);
  }
  /*read_Icecream: Chama o método snapshotChanges , que obterá registros e também será registrado para receber atualizações */
  read_userPrincipal(){
    return this.firestore.collection('user').snapshotChanges();
  }
  read_feddUser(key:string){
    return this.firestore.collection('feed').get;
  }
  update_like(recordID,record) {
   return this.firestore.doc('feed/' + recordID).update(record);
  }
  carregar_publicacao(){
    return this.firestore.collection('feed').snapshotChanges();
  }

}
```

meu componente

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Publicacao } from './publi.model';
import { TestService } from 'src/app/test.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-publi',
  templateUrl: './publi.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./publi.component.css']
})
export class PubliComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() publicacao: Publicacao

  constructor(private testeService: TestService) { }


  ngOnInit(){}

  like(item){
    let arrey;
    arrey = this.testeService.read_feddUser(item.token)
    console.log(arrey)
  }
}
```

nessa função like é onde eu preciso ler apenas o item com a key dele.

Answer (score 0):

É possível verificar alguns problemas no método `read_feddUser`.

`get` é um método. Sendo assim, é necessário alterar para `get()`.

Embora receba um parâmetro (`key:string`), ele não é usado. Neste caso você não conseguiria retornar um item pelo seu ID. Sendo necessário alterar para

```js
this.firestore.collection('feed').doc(key).get();
```

Você retorna o `get()` do firestore para o seu componente e `get()` retorna um promisse. Sendo assim, é necessário alterar o seu componente para ler a promisse. Algo mais ou menos assim:

```js
like(item) {
  let feed;
  this.testeService.read_feddUser(item.token)
  .then(function(doc) {
    feed = doc;
    console.log(feed);
  }
```

Comment: eu coloquei a função como você mostrou ai e ela da erro de compilação

Comment: read_feddUser(key:string){
   return firebase.firestore().collection('feed').doc(key).get();
  }

Comment: import * as firebase from 'firebase'; tive que importar o firebase para conseguir usar, é esse import mesmo?

Comment: ERROR in ./firebase 37:8
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (37:8)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|           })
|           console.log(this.publicacoes)
>         }
| 
|

Comment: no teu caso deve ser `this.firestore.collection('feed').doc(key).get();` corrigi na resposta.

Comment: funcionou @jvl?

Comment: colocando assim o erro realmente some do service porém da erro no componente na função then

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document

Comment: @jvl verifique como está na documentação, neste link acima

Comment: simm porém fazendo como esta la também da erro pois fala que get não é uma função e que then também não é uma função.

Comment: return this.firestore.collection('feed').doc(key).get(); se eu deixo a minha função no service assim e a função no component assim let feed ;
    feed = this.testeService.read_feddUser(item.token)
    console.log(feed) ele me retorna um Observable como eu consigo acessar as propriedades nesse Observable no curso que eu fiz eu não entendi quase nada de Observable